# In IE, this :not(:nth-child():nth-last-child()) declaration isn't working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-7

I have the following CSS.

```
.formhidden                     {overflow: hidden}

.formhidden[id*='petinfo_']
                                {height: 48px}
.formhidden[id*='petproblem_']
                                {height: 0px}

[id*='petinfo_']:not(.formhidden)
                                {outline: 1px solid black; padding: 24px 12px 12px}
[id*='petproblem_']:not(.formhidden)
                                {outline: 1px solid black; padding: 24px 12px 12px}
[id*='petinfo_']:not(.formhidden):not(nth-child(2))
                                {margin-top: -24px}
[id*='petproblem_']:not(.formhidden)
                                {margin-top: -24px}
[id*='petinfo_']:not(.formhidden) + div + [id*='petinfo_']
                                {margin-top: 24px}
[id*='petproblem_']:not(.formhidden) + [id*='petinfo_']
                                {margin-top: 24px}

/* For any pet div with the formhidden class, hide all,
but reveal the pet's name unless it's the only pet so far.
This is sensitive to position from first and last sibling. */
.formhidden[id*='petinfo_'] *:not(:nth-child(4)):not(:nth-child(5)),
.formhidden[id*='petinfo_']:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4) *,
.formhidden[id*='petproblem_'] *,
#ownerform.formhidden,
.formhidden.form_btn            {visibility: hidden; height: 0px}

.formhidden[id*='petinfo_']:not(:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4))
                                {outline: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 24px}
```

Within a form, there are the following divs, separating sections of the form with the labels and inputs within these divs.

```
<div id="ownerform"></div>
<div id="petinfo_0"></div>
<div id="petproblem_0"></div>
<div id="html_element_recaptcha"></div>
<div class="buttonholder"></div>
```

To put it simply, the class ".formhidden" hides a section when it's applied. I have javascript applying and removing it from the sections so only one is visible at a time. The javascript also clones petinfo_0 and petproblem_0 and increments the 0 to the appropriate number.

It works great in Chrome and Firefox. But when I try it in IE (Edge), that last CSS declaration doesn't work.

```
.formhidden[id*='petinfo_']:not(:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4))
                                {outline: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 24px}
```

It's meant to exclude petinfo_0 if we haven't added any more sections yet. (In our initial state, it is the 2nd div from the front and 4th div from the end.)

I've been trying for hours to figure out what's wrong, but nothing works.

EDIT: In hindsight, I'm actually finding that none of the outlines are appearing, except for the one section that is being shown at the moment. So it would seem that none of those declarations with the outline in it, are working.

Comment: I’m a bit confused. :not is not supported in IE see https://caniuse.com/?search=not so that would be an explanation for the problem as posed in your title. However in your text you say IE(Edge). Are you saying that it doesn’t work in a current version of Edge? Note that Edge is not associated with IE now but is Chromium based.

Comment: Oh... well that solves it I guess!

I wasn't sure which one I was using. I checked now, and it is IE11.

Comment: One site says it works though, and one says it doesn't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seems like I have to just override it if it IS nth-child(x):last-child(y). Additionally, IE does not support unset, so we have to explicitly override it with a value.

This worked out for me:

```
    .formhidden[id*='petinfo_']
                                    {outline: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 24px}

    .formhidden[id*='petinfo_']:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(4)
                                    {outline: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As we can known from the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#description), using two selectors at the same time is not yet supported in all browsers.

If you want to use them in IE, just replace it to :

```
.formhidden[id*='petinfo_']:not(:nth-child(2)):not(:nth-last-child(4)) {
                outline: 1px solid black;
                margin-bottom: 24px
            }
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work either, and it also makes it stop working in Chrome too.